# Apply css styling in print paper

Tags: css, printing, styling

I have some reports in HTML format and want print them in my web application. The problem I have is that I can not force printing operation to apply css properties to coloring header and footer.

`<td style="background-color:gray">Total</td>`

I expect to see a gray background color row in the printed paper, but everything is white as cells background color.

What do I have to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the styles via a media query? Either like this in a `<style>` block:

```
@media print {
    td { background-color: gray; }
}
```

Or like this in a link in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="your/print/css.ss" />
```

In case you're not aware of print stylesheets here's a good article on it http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: I've tested your suggestions @MrMisterMan. They did not solve my problem. But thank you for your valuable recommended link.

Comment: I'm glad I was of some use! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a setting with whatever software you are using to print this page.

If you are using a web browser, the browser may be removing the colours to save ink etc.

These settings can usually be changed within the browser software itself. I don't think there is anything you can change on your web application to force this `background-color`.